# Retrieving a value from a function in ngStyle

Tags: angularjs

I am a beginner in angularjs and I am sure there must be an easy solution to it but I can't pin it. I am trying to get style for an element through a function, however unsucessfully. Here is the code:

```
Script.js:
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('docsBindExample', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.color = "{'background-color':'red'}";
    $scope.fetchStyle = function(){
      return {'background-color':'red'};
    };
    $scope.name = 'Max Karl Ernst Ludwig Planck (April 23, 1858 – October 4, 1947)';
  }]);
})(window.angular);

Index.html:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example9-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="docsBindExample">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
  Hello <input ng-model='name'> <hr/>
  <span ng-bind="name" ng-style="fetchColor()"></span> <br/>
  <span ng:bind="name"></span> <br/>
  <span ng_bind="name"></span> <br/>
  <span data-ng-bind="name"></span> <br/>
  <span x-ng-bind="name"></span> <br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using fetchColor() to get the color for the span. Is there some syntax mistake or something else? All responses appreciated.

Comment: You're not even starting angular, you confuse function names: fetchStyle with fetchColor. I'm giving you a downvote for not showing any effort.

Comment: @kihu `ng-app="docsBindExample"` will start angular

Comment: oh, my bad. I cancelled my downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-style` needs an expression. Also you are using `fetchColor()` in markup but have `fetchStyle()` in controller

Try

```
<span ng-bind="name" ng-style="{{fetchStyle()}}"></span> <br/>
<span ng:bind="name" ng-style="{{color}}"></span> <br/>
```

In addition you are creating a string for `$scope.color`

Change:

```
$scope.color = "{'background-color':'red'}";
```

To

```
$scope.color = {'background-color':'red'};
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/SpaKMqW4ER65TDxcKGsS?p=preview)**</kbd>